# How to add a second sticky navbar on scroll of a particular section, under the primary fixed-top navbar, in jquery & bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I have a page with one fixed-top navbar.
Then I have 3 sections.
In 2nd section I have nav-tabs.
Upon scrolling into the 2nd section, I want the nav-tabs navbar to stick to top, below my fixed-top navbar. When user has scrolled out of the 2nd section, the nav-tabs navbar should disappear and only the fixed-top navbar must remain.

I can not find any tutorials or guidance related to what I'm trying to achieve.
Any idea how to do this in bootstrap 5 using jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive this by having primary navbar fixed or sticky does not matter.  Just set the position of the required heading to `position-sticky` not `sticky-top` which sticks to top which you don't want. what you want is a secondary nav bar below the primary so `css` is helpfull set `top` to `12%` or whatever you need just test it. This is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shahsawood/b5mfjsxc/4/) link.

```
<section>
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias, sint fuga ipsam soluta maxime in est ipsa modi explicabo impedit natus, dolore eum, voluptas sequi dicta ullam placeat expedita quos.</p>
</section>
<section>
    <h1 class="position-sticky" style="z-index: 2;top:10%">Section 2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias, sint fuga ipsam soluta maxime in est ipsa modi explicabo impedit natus, dolore eum, voluptas sequi dicta ullam placeat expedita quos.</p>
</section>
<section>
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias, sint fuga ipsam soluta maxime in est ipsa modi explicabo impedit natus, dolore eum, voluptas sequi dicta ullam placeat expedita quos.</p>
</section>
```